# Filter specificaly with hour/minutes/seconds - R

Tags: r, time, timestamp

I have this `df`:

```
> Time
[1] "02:15:00" "02:30:00" "02:45:00" "03:00:00" "03:15:00" "03:30:00"
```

I wanna delete all the time values before `3:00:00`. However, I need to do it in a format of `hour = 3`, `minutes = 0`, `seconds = 0`. Like:

```
df <- df[df$Time < a_function(hour=3, minutes=0, seconds=0) ,]
```

I want to know how can I do this with time values, as I can do it with year, month, and day.

Comment: Sample data would be useful. Take a look at `ISOdatetime`. Might help you with your problem in conjunction with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it that way? Just asking for context. Also have you looked at lubridate::hms()? It takes a time object and converts to periods of time.

Comment: Yeah ! It's in lubridate. I want to do that because I have a huge dataset where the daytime are in intervals of 15 minutes, and I just need the intervals after 8am and before 7pm.

Comment: If you can provide an example of what your data already looks like and some code that you've already tried I will attempt to provide an answer